# Change background textbox in SSRS when date exceed the expected date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, background-color

I doing some reporting designing in SSRS and I encounter this problem.
I wanted to make if **OVERALL EXPECTED DATE** exceeds the date and the **SHIPMENT STATUS = IN PROGRESS**, the background will change to **pink**.

[Click here for image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5akua.png)

I tried so many ways but still didn't manage to get it right.

> =IIF(Fields!Shipment_Status.Value = "IN PROGRESS" AND Fields!Overall_Expected_Date.Value > Fields!Overall_Expected_Date.Value, "Pink","Transparent")

I know it still wrong and really appreciate the help on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a field value to itself so it will never be greater.

Assuming you want to compare it to the current date AND `Overall_Expected_Date` is actually a date, then try the following

```
=IIF(Fields!Shipment_Status.Value = "IN PROGRESS" AND Fields!Overall_Expected_Date.Value > Today(), "Pink", Nothing)
```

Comment: It's works !! but if I wanted to make Overall_Expected_Date less than today date, i just make it like this right ? =IIF(Fields!Shipment_Status.Value = "IN PROGRESS" AND Fields!Overall_Expected_Date.Value < Today(), "Pink", Nothing)

Comment: Assuming that Overall_Expected_Date is actually a date data type then yes. If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the vote up/down buttons to the left)